# how to extract the front and back of a designated special token using regex?

Tags: python, regex

How to extract the front and back of a designated special token(in this case, -, not @)?
And if those that are connected by - are more than two, I want to extract those too.  (In the example, Bill-Gates-Foundation)

e.g)
from 'Meinda@Bill-Gates-Foundation@drug-delivery' -> ['Bill-Gates-Foundation', 'drug-delivery']

I tried `p = re.compile('@(\D+)\*(\D+)')`

but that was not what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude matchting the `@` char and repeat 1 or more times the `-`

```
@([^\s@-]+(?:-[^\s@-]+)+)
```

**Explanation**

- `@` Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 1** (returned by re.findall)

  - `[^\s@-]+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars except `-` and `@`
  - `(?:-[^\s@-]+)+` Repeat 1+ times matching `-` and again 1+ non whitespace chars except `-` and `@`
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9ox7xs/1)

```
import re

pattern = r"@([^\s@-]+(?:-[^\s@-]+)+)"
s = r"Meinda@Bill-Gates-Foundation@drug-delivery"
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['Bill-Gates-Foundation', 'drug-delivery']
```

Comment: Actually because I have to find the pattern (front and end of '-') in various text patterns, this helped me most. So I changed the selection of best answer.. Thanks ..

Answer (score 1):

@ahmet-buğra-buĞa gave an answer with regex.

If you don't have to use regex, then it is easier way is to just use split.

```
test_str = "Meinda@Bill-Gates-Foundation@drug-delivery"
test_str.split("@")[1:]
```

This outputs

```
['Bill-Gates-Foundation', 'drug-delivery']
```

You can make it a function like so

```
def get_list_of_strings_after_first(original_str, token_to_split_on):
    return original_str.split("@")[1:]
get_list_of_strings_after_first("Meinda@Bill-Gates-Foundation@drug-delivery", "@")
```

This give the same output

```
['Bill-Gates-Foundation', 'drug-delivery']
```